# UITableViewCell to cover the entire screen in Grouped mode?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Is it possible when a table view is set to grouped mode to have a special kind of cell that covers the entire table view width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you don't want to do a regular table with the top and bottom cells having a custom background that gives it a rounded corner? (This would be easier than trying to force a grouped table view into something it isn't meant to be.)